# Use stereo out headphone jack as stereo input/AUX

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsa, jack

**The Overall Problem:** Sonos speakers are great, but it's pretty well known on their community forum that there isn't an easy way to use them as computer speakers.

**What I have so far:** I have successfully been able to create an Icecast2 stream from the audio coming from my computer's mic input (using `darkice`) and use the [`soco-cli`](https://github.com/avantrec/soco-cli) to instruct a sonos device to play that stream.

**The problem:** because my intended use for this is to have a raspberry pi connected to a sonos and use the raspberry pi's audio jack as an AUX in for playing music to the sonos, I am now trying to see if it is possible for me to use the stereo output jack as an input, rather than an output so that I can basically create an aux input port to stream to the sonos.

**What i've tried:** i saw [an article](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/12/turn-headphone-jack-microphone-jack-ubuntu) that mentions an app called HDA-Jack-Retask. I have tried installing this but it seems like the only options available for remapping my headphone port are all other outputs (wasnt able to screenshot the dropdown menu, but the options are things like: Headphone, line out, internal speaker, dock headphone, dock line out, not connected). *Is there any other way to treat an audio out port as an audio input under linux?*

**Additional Info:**

`lspci` line for my laptop's audio:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
```

`aplay -l`

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC257 Analog [ALC257 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: DA45 [Plantronics DA45], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTWju6hsWII) seems like it may be helpful. surprised it doesnt have more views...

Comment: also related: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4341/can-i-get-audio-input-through-the-gpio#7528

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=298932&p=1798210&hilit=Audio+input#p1798210

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=286387&p=1733042&hilit=%22Audio+input%22#p1733042

Comment: bluetooth input is another option